# Another riddle: "Passes invisibly, / Never stopping..."

Tags: riddle

Another riddle:

> Passes invisibly,
> Never stopping.
> Slowly and inexorably,
> Or quick and jumping.
> Was here at the start of the start,
> Will be here till the end of the end.

What is it?

Comment: Where did this riddle come from?

Comment: Created it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is most likely

> Time

> Passes invisibly,
> Never stopping.

> It passes without us seeing it, and you can't stop it, no one can.

> Slowly and inexorably,
> Or quick and jumping.

> Time can pass very slowly or very fast depending on who you ask, or even how they're feeling

> Was here at the start of the start,
> Will be here till the end of the end.

> Time is one of the fundamentals of the universe, it passes and rules everything. And even though it is only a mortal concept, time has been here long before us, and will be here long after us too.

Additional trivia:

> Even though time is here, and will be, there will be a time when time will become meaningless, some call this as the End of Time, it's a time where nothing exists anymore in the Universe, where time doesn't change anything anymore by passing.